# How set git project to release recipe in Yocto by 'devtool finish' command?

Tags: git, yocto, recipe

In yocto project I created, built and tested recipe with devtool. When I try to release it I heve problem with command:

```
$ devtool finish helloappjarek ../meta-jarmod/recipes/
```

I receive

```
ERROR: Unable to find initial revision - please specify it with --initial-rev
```

I know that problem is with git but I don't know how to fix it. The source code for this recipe is in other directory than poky and in this folder git is initialised and commited.
Actually I have two recipes in development phase as you can see:

```
poky/build$ devtool status
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
helloappjarek: /home/votex/usr/mysource/helloapp (/home/votex/dist-thud/poky/meta-jarmod/recipes/helloappjarek/helloappjarek_0.1.bb)
nano: /home/votex/dist-thud/poky/meta-jarmod/sources/nano (/home/votex/dist-thud/poky/meta-jarmod/recipes/nano/nano_3.2.bb)
```

I tried to set option '--initial-rev' in several ways without success.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is described in places like https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I had read this document earlier and there is mentioned only commit requirement what I did. Today I found that in my project (configure.ac) is a line `AC_INIT(helloapp,0.1)` and maybe here I made some mistake.

Comment: Maybe add here generated recipe by devtool? You can try to create it by hand otherwise by following steps [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#building-software-from-an-external-source). Another way is to create a private git repo online see if it changes anything.